# Python - BeautifulSoup - Selecting a 'div' with 'class'-attribute shows every div in the html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl coinmarketcap.com with BeautifulSoup (I know there is an API, for training purposes, I want to use BeautifulSoup). Every piece of information crawled so far was pretty easy to select, but now I like to get the "Holder Statistics" looking like this:

[holder stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRoWn.png)

My testing code for selecting the specific div containing the desired information looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/holders/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
holders = soup.select('div', class_='n0m7sa-0 kkBhMM')
print(holders)
```

The output of *print(holders)* is not the expected content of the div, but rather the whole html content of the website. I append a picture of this because the output code would be too long.

[Output Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDLs5.png)

Does anybody know, why this is the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `.select()` when you want to use as css selector. In this case, `holders = soup.select('div', class_='n0m7sa-0 kkBhMM')` the class part is essentially ignored...and it finds all the `<div>` with any class. To specify that particular class use either the `.find_all()`, or change your `.select()`

`holders = soup.select('div.n0m7sa-0.kkBhMM')`

or

`holders = soup.find_all('div', class_='n0m7sa-0 kkBhMM')`

Now in both of these cases, it will return `None` or an empty list. That is because that class attribute is not in the source html. This site is dynamic, so those classes are generated after the initial request. So you either need to use Selenium to render the page first, then pull the html, or see if there's an api to get the data source directly.

There is an api to get the data:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

alpha = ['count', 'ratio']
payload = {
'id': '1',
'range': '7d'}


for each in alpha:
        url = f'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/cryptocurrency/detail/holders/{each}'
        jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()['data']['points']
        
        if each == 'count':
            count_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(jsonData,orient='index')
            count_df = count_df.rename(columns={0:'Total Addresses'})
            
        else:
            ratio_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(jsonData,orient='index')
            df = count_df.merge(ratio_df, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
            
df = df.sort_index()
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
                      Total Addresses  topTenHolderRatio  topTwentyHolderRatio  topFiftyHolderRatio  topHundredHolderRatio
2021-11-24T00:00:00Z         39279627               5.25                  7.19                10.51                  13.26
2021-11-25T00:00:00Z         39255811               5.25                  7.19                10.49                  13.22
2021-11-26T00:00:00Z         39339840               5.25                  7.19                10.51                  13.24
2021-11-27T00:00:00Z         39391849               5.23                  7.11                10.45                  13.18
2021-11-28T00:00:00Z         39505340               5.24                  7.11                10.45                  13.18
2021-11-29T00:00:00Z         39502099               5.24                  7.11                10.43                  13.16
2021-11-30T00:00:00Z         39523000               5.24                  7.11                10.38                  13.12
```

Your Other option is that the data is within the `<script>` tags in json format. S0 you can pull it out from the initial request site that way too:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import re

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/holders/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

jsonStr = str(soup.find('script', {'id':'__NEXT_DATA__'}))
jsonStr = re.search(r"({.*})", jsonStr).groups()[0]
jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)['props']['initialProps']['pageProps']['info']['holders']

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData).drop('holderList', axis=1).drop_duplicates()
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
   holderCount  dailyActive  topTenHolderRatio  topTwentyHolderRatio  topFiftyHolderRatio  topHundredHolderRatio
0     39523000       963625               5.24                  7.11                10.38                  13.12
```

For the Social Stats in the Project Info, that's within a specific api:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/data-api/v3/project-info/detail?slug=bitcoin'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()
socialStats = jsonData['data']['socialStats']

row = {}
for k, v in socialStats.items():
    if type(v) == dict:
        row.update(v)
    else:
        row.update({k:v})
        
df = pd.DataFrame([row])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
   cryptoId commits contributors  stars  forks watchers              lastCommitAt  members               updatedTime
0         1   31588          836  59687  30692     3881  2021-11-30T00:09:02.000Z  3617460  2021-11-30T16:00:02.365Z
```

Comment: Can you explain to me in detail why the return of find_all will be None? My initial guess was the dynamic rendering, too. But when i open the specific link "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/holders/", the content is already in the dom-tree. dont judge me please, this whole crwaling-thing is new to me :)

Comment: no judgement at all! The dom-tree you are viewing is rendered after the initial request is made (with javascript). The `request` package doesn't execute java script, so you just get the static html response. I added to the solution above as well as there is an api to get the data

Comment: @MxclFhn I also did find the data within the `<script>` tags in the init request. So you could go that route too

Comment: Agree with @chitown88 about extracting data from `<script>` tags. There's no real need in `selenium` as mentioned in another answer since it will slow the extraction process for a bit (*or a lot*).

Comment: Thank you everyone, i appreciate the suggested solutions, i will try them :)

Comment: @chitown88 Your suggested solution worked out pretty well, thank you :) unfortunatly i probably need to use selenium tough, because i cannot find the other desired information in the <script>-tag, for example the social stats. But for the 'Holders' problem, this actually worked out :))

Comment: @MxclFhn what do you mean by social stats? Where on the site is that?

Comment: @chitown88 its this url: https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/project-info/ . 
on the left side, you can see "Team", "Investors" and "Social Stats". It was difficult for me to even find the holders in the script tag (due to never working with this kind of things before), but for this data, i have no clue, how to crawl it apart from using selenium.

Comment: @MxclFhn. I get it. I was the same. Just takes practice and seeing other ways to get it. For example, here you can see theres an api to get that. Check out the edit above. You find that url by opeing dev tools (ctrl-shift-i), and look at Network -> XHR -> Headers; to see the url. You might need to refresh to see it pop in the panel.

Answer (score 0):

*As chitown88 already mentioned content is served dynamical, so an alternativ solution could be selenium.*

##### How to select?

In case you get the `html` with [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/getting_started/how_to_upgrade_to_selenium_4/) you should avoid to select the elements by class, cause they are also generate dynamically.

Select the `<h3>` taht contains *Holders Statistics* and all its `<span>` without child `<span>`:

```
soup.select('h3:-soup-contains("Holders Statistics") ~ div :not(span)')
```

##### Example based on [Selenium 4](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/getting_started/how_to_upgrade_to_selenium_4/)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
service = ChromeService(executable_path='YOUR PATH TO CHROM DRIVER')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/holders/')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

data = {x.get_text('|').split('|')[0]:x.get_text('|').split('|')[1] for x in soup.select('h3:-soup-contains("Holders Statistics") ~ div :not(span)')}
print(data)

driver.close()
```

##### Output

```
{'Total Addresses': '39,523,000',
 'Active Addresses': '24h',
 'Top 10 Holders': '5.24%',
 'Top 20 Holders': '7.11%',
 'Top 50 Holders': '10.38%',
 'Top 100 Holders': '13.12%'}
```